# What is the syntax in R for returning the number of words matched in regular expression?

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

R Package: stringr::words

I want to know the number of words that are exactly three letters long in the stringr::words file after applying the following regular expression:

```
x <- str_view(words, "^...$", match = TRUE)
```

While the code was able to extract words that are exactly three letters long, it does not tell me how many words there are. So, I thought the length function will be appropriate to find the number.

```
length(x)
```

The code returns 8, which cannot be as it is very clear that x is more than 8.

What is the proper syntax to calculate the number of words after matching with the regular expression, in this case, x?

Also, can anyone explain to me why length(x) returns 8 in the above example?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str_view` returns an HTML object which is used for viewing.

```
x <- str_view(words, "^...$", match = TRUE)
class(x)
#[1] "str_view"   "htmlwidget"
```

The 8 components that you see are

```
names(x)
#[1] "x"             "width"         "height"        "sizingPolicy"  "dependencies" 
#[6] "elementId"     "preRenderHook" "jsHooks"
```

Instead of `str_view` use `str_subset` :

```
library(stringr)

x <- str_subset(words, "^...$")
x

#  [1] "act" "add" "age" "ago" "air" "all" "and" "any" "arm" "art" "ask" "bad" "bag"
# [14] "bar" "bed" "bet" "big" "bit" "box" "boy" "bus" "but" "buy" "can" "car" "cat"
# [27] "cup" "cut" "dad" "day" "die" "dog" "dry" "due" "eat" "egg" "end" "eye" "far"
# [40] "few" "fit" "fly" "for" "fun" "gas" "get" "god" "guy" "hit" "hot" "how" "job"
# [53] "key" "kid" "lad" "law" "lay" "leg" "let" "lie" "lot" "low" "man" "may" "mrs"
# [66] "new" "non" "not" "now" "odd" "off" "old" "one" "out" "own" "pay" "per" "put"
# [79] "red" "rid" "run" "say" "see" "set" "sex" "she" "sir" "sit" "six" "son" "sun"
# [92] "tax" "tea" "ten" "the" "tie" "too" "top" "try" "two" "use" "war" "way" "wee"
#[105] "who" "why" "win" "yes" "yet" "you"


length(x)
#[1] 110
```

Comment: Thank you, Ronak.
I have a follow-up question if you do not mind. 

How important are the components of the names(x) in the example above? I mean what are their significance if any, do you know?

Also, can you explain why the following code does not return all three-letter words?

str_subset(words, c("^y", "x$", "^...$", "......."))

I was expecting the match for the different conditions but it seems some of them were omitted.

Thank you.

Comment: `str_view` is used only for viewing purposes, so those names and the information in it are not really important for any kind of string manipulation. Also, you cannot include multiple conditions in the same `str_subset` command. If you want output of each of them differently pass them separately. `str_subset(words, "^y")`, `str_subset(words, "^x")` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `str_count`:

```
library(stringr)
sum(str_count(x, "^...$"))
[1] 3
```

Data:

```
x <- c("abc", "abcd", "ab", "abc", "abcsd", "edf")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `grep` with `length`:

```r
length(grep("^.{3}$", words))
# => [1] 110
```

With `grep`, you actually get a subset of the `words` and `length` will return the count of the found matches.

[`stringr::str_view`](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringr/man/str_view.html) can be used to view HTML rendering of regular expression match, and it does not actually return the list of matches. Beside `grep`, you may use `stringr::str_subset`.